# Quasi-linear PDE $(1-xy)u_x+u_y+u_z=(y-z)u$ in 3 variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How do I go about solving $(1-xy)u_x+u_y+u_z=(y-z)u$? I know how to solve quasi-linear PDEs with 2 independent variables, but solving with three is giving me problems.

So me and my friend are trying to self learn PDEs. We're not sure how to do it without boundary conditions. (How is it different?) But with a boundary condition, say $u(y,0)=f(y)$ for some function $f(y)$, let $y(0)=s$, $z(0)=0$, and $w(0)=f(y)$, then we have $dy/dt=1⟹y=t+s$, $dz/dt=1⟹z=t$, and $dw/dt=(y−z)w=sw⟹w=f(y)e^{st}$, so $u(y,z)=f(y)e^{(y−z)z}$. This is quite the problem we run into when trying to solve the 3-variable PDE I posted; how does $u(x,y,z)$ depend on $x$?

Comment: Have you tried with the method of characteristics?

Comment: Yes I have but I am getting stuck, could you walk me through it?

Comment: At least can you solve $u_y+u_z=(y-z)u$ ? Show us how you find the general solution (without boundary condition) .

Comment: @JJacquelin So me and my friend are trying to self learn PDEs. We're not sure how to do it without boundary conditions. (How is it different?) But with a boundary condition, say $u(y,0)=f(y)$ for some function $f(y)$, let $y(0)=s, z(0)=0,$ and $w(0)=f(y)$, then we have $\frac{dy}{dt}=1\implies y=t+s$, $\frac{dz}{dt}=1\implies z=t$, and $\frac{dw}{dt}=(y-z)w=sw\implies w=f(y)e^{st}$, so $u(y,z)=f(y)e^{(y-z)z}$. This is quite the problem we run into when trying to solve the 3-variable PDE I posted; how does $u(x,y,z)$ depend on $x$?

Comment: Your solution $u(y,z)=f(y)e^{(y-z)z}$ is false. Check it in putting in the PDE. The correct solution is $$u(y,z)=f(y-z)e^{(y-z)z}$$ Note that this solution is also a solution of the original PDE $(1-xy)u_x+u_y+u_z=(y-z)u$. That is why you should edit it IN YOUR QUESTION as an usefull attempt. This would avoid your question to be downvoted or possibly deleted.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1-xy)u_x+u_y+u_z=(y-z)u$$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics

Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$ds=\frac{dx}{1-xy}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dz}{1}=\frac{du}{(y-z)u}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dz}{1}$ :
$$y-z=c_1$$

A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{1-xy}=\frac{dy}{1}$ :
$$x \: e^{\frac12 y^2}-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \: \text{erfi}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=c_2$$
This is not a simple function, but the equation of a characteristic curve involving a special function namely erfi : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html

A third characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dz}{1}=\frac{ydy-zdz}{y-z}=\frac{du}{(y-z)u}$ :
$$e^{-\frac12(y^2-z^2)}u=c_3$$

The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation
is $\Phi\left(c_1,c_2,c_3\right)=0$ where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function of three variables. Or explicitly $u=e^{\frac12(y^2-z^2)}F(c_1,c_2)$ :
$$\boxed{u(x,y,z)=e^{\frac12(y^2-z^2)}F\left((y-z)\:\: , \:\:x \: e^{\frac12 y^2}-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \: \text{erfi}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)}$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function of two variables.

The function $F$ has to be determined if some boundary conditions are specified.

Comment: Thank you! I know this is on the Wikipedia page, but it still doesn't make much sense: we have $u=c_3e^{\frac{1}{2}(y^2-z^2)}$, but why is $c_3$ some arbitrary function of $c_1$ and $c_2$?

Comment: $c_3$is an arbitrary function of $c_1$ and $c_2$ as well as $c_1$is an arbitrary function of $c_2$ and $c_3$ as well as $c_2$is an arbitrary function of $c_1$ and $c_3$ until no boundary condion is specified. If there was boundary conditions specified  in the wording of the problem (or if some boundary conditions are introduced in order to solve the problem as you did) the relationship between $c_1,c_2,c_3$, that is the function $\Phi$ in the implicit solution $\Phi(c_1,c_2,c_3)=0$ is no longer arbitrary but becomes a determined function involving the given boundary conditions